# Force method run during specified interval of time

Tags: java

I want to force method run for specified time.

```
 public Response run(Request req){
    //method runImpl must run during specified interval of time(for example for 10 secs)
    Response res = runImpl(req);
    return response;
    }
```

What is the best way to do this?Thanks!

Comment: Implementing a Speed Up Loop? http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Speedup-Loop.aspx

Comment: What do you mean with "run during specified interval"? Should it complete within that interval? Only return after that interval? Be called continuously during that interval?

Comment: Your use of the word "during" here is very confusing.

Comment: Do you want this function to loop on an interval, stall the process until 10 seconds have passed, or break if 10 seconds have passed and it's not done?

Comment: I mean if interval equals 10 secs, function stops executing after this period of time and returns null. Maybe I can use Thread class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

runImpl should return a boolean for this code to work. You'll probably want this in a new Thread (basic tutorials abound) if you don't want your program stalled until it finishes.

```
public Response run(Request req){
long lasttime=Sys.getTime();
int i=0;
while(i<10){
   if(Response res = runImpl(req);){
   return response;
   }
   if((Sys.getTime-lasttime)>1000){
   i++;
   lasttime=Sys.getTime();
   }
}
return null;
```

This runs every processor moment, if you want it to run on an interval AS WELL as running for 10 seconds, use:

```
public Response run(Request req){
long lasttime=Sys.getTime();
int i=0;
for(int i; i<(10000/yourchoiceinterval); i++){
   if(Response res = runImpl(req);){
   return response;
   }
   if((Sys.getTime-lasttime)>1000){
   lasttime=Sys.getTime();
   }
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this:

```
poolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
poolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new YourRunable(), startFrom/*10*/, startEvery/*5*/, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is it . That's what I meant!

Comment: this doesn't enforce that the runnable runs for a maximum of X seconds - it's intended to kick off the runnable starting in N seconds and re-invoking every M seconds

Answer (score 1):

Best method would be to make your work in chunks of appropriate size, so each chunk can be done in, say, 1 second. This way at the end of each chunk you can check if time is elapsed.

If your work involves I/O work which can block for indefinite time, try to use interruptible methods (which can be interrupted by call to `Thread.interrupt()`) or methods which accept explicit max running time from caller.
Or you can delegate I/O work to some dedicated thread and check it's progress in separate thread, and act appropriately when running time is exceeded.

Comment: What to do if during some chunk execution function "hangs"?

Comment: @Martin I assumed that there are no steps which can "hang", with any reasonable probability. If there are such steps, for example, network I/O, use one thread for I/O and other to check I/O progress and abort I/O as soon as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a new thread that only calls your method and put it to sleep after a timer you create expires. That way though you can't guarantee that the method cycle has completed before suspending, but does the trick without having to modify the method. For you to achieve cycles, just put this logic of sleeping inside the thread's loop. Just remember to wake up the thread

There may be dozens of implementations since you didn't explained clear enough.